# How to exclude 1 ip from iptable rules?

Tags: 18.04, iptables

I want to block all ip's with > 200 connections to access my server with this rule:

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 100:65535 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 200 -j REJECT

but at the same time I want to allow 1 IP to have unlimited connections.

So rule would be: If connections more then 200, block all ip's, except 1 IP: xxx

how do i do it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to bypass the block rule by preceding it with an ACCEPT rule for the special IP address. Something like (using the IP address from your other question):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 87.91.143.119 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 100:65535 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 200 -j REJECT
```